# what is the proper type for process.stdin in typescript/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a variable that can be `fs.createReadStream('file-path')` or `process.stdin`:

```
const input: any = filePath ? fs.createReadStream(filePath) : process.stdin;
```

but I'm not sure about which type I must use. So I wonder if both returning are either of type `net.Socket`, `fs.ReadStream` or `stream.Redable`.

What is the suitable type to replace `any`? Would the declaration below be correct?

```
let input: null | NodeJS.ReadStream = null;
input: any = filePath ? fs.createReadStream(filePath) : process.stdin;
```

Comment: `typeof process.stdin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a full answer as to what you should use, but *how* you can find it.

I specify types like you do, but if you really want to know what the type[s] could be, simply don't specify one. VS Code will then tell you the proper type when you hover over the variable name. You can even copy it from the intellisense window and paste it into the editor.

[image: screenshot of vs code's intellisense for type inference]

```
    const filePath: fs.PathLike = '';    
    const input = filePath ? fs.createReadStream(filePath) : process.stdin;
```

So based on this, the proper type is:

```
    const filePath: fs.PathLike = '';    
    const input: fs.ReadStream | (NodeJS.ReadStream & { fd: 0; }) = 
        filePath ? fs.createReadStream(filePath) : process.stdin;
```

Of course, this is for my current setup and yours may vary by version.

Comment: `fs` is a beast, by the way. There are so many overloads that Typescript has trouble selecting the correct method sometimes, so your ultimate type will vary based on what was passed in and how the path was defined. In a prior case, I had a file path and TS was correct, but `fs` thought it was a buffer when it was actually running. (Not for this method, just an FYI for others who find this and think it may be their answer)